# Flesch-Kincaid readability test

Tags: c#, readability, flesch-kincaid

Are there any opensource .Net libraries that handle Flesch-Kincaid readability calculations?

Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch-Kincaid_readability_test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not open source, but you could delegate to Word using [the ReadabilityStatistic interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.readabilitystatistic%28v=office.14%29.aspx).  Even if your document isn't in Word to begin with, you could open Word (invisibly to the user), dump your text into Word, and then use `ReadabilityStatistic` to calculate the statistics.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the Flesch-Kincaid grade level formula:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_tests

you need to count words, sentences, and syllables. Syllables are perhaps the most tricky, though sentences also require some thought.

Here is are two translations of other people's code for syllable counting to F# (which is .NET, you can create an F# project in visual studio and then reference that project from your C# project). I've done basic but not extensive tests of this.

I find that the Ipeirotis gives better results on some of my test cases (once I add the problem word list) than the Child. My test words are:

```
let testWords = [|"abalone";"gracious";"atheism";"unaware"; "seaside";"underwater";"wonderwoman";"biology"|]
```

Child's code particularly has a problem with the end of the list. Reordering the regular expressions from longest affix to shortest doesn't seem to solve it.

My translation:

```
module Readability

open System.Text.RegularExpressions
//for syllables
//simpler:
//https://github.com/ipeirotis/ReadabilityMetrics/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ipeirotis/readability/engine/Syllabify.java

let SyllableCount2 (word:string) =
    let SubSyl = [| "cial"; "tia"; "cius"; "cious"; "giu"; "ion"; "iou"; "sia$"; ".ely$" |]
    let AddSyl = [| "ia"; "riet"; "dien"; "iu"; "io"; "ii"; "[aeiouym]bl$"; "[aeiou]{3}"; "^mc"; "ism$"; "[^aeiouy][^aeiouy]l$"; "[^l]lien"; "^coa[dglx]."; "[^gq]ua[^auieo]"; "dnt$" |]

    let mutable tempWord = word.ToLower()
    tempWord <- tempWord.Replace("'", " ")

    if problemWordMap.ContainsKey( word ) then
        problemWordMap.[word]
    else if tempWord = "i" || tempWord = "a" then
        1
    else
        if tempWord.EndsWith("e") then
            tempWord <- tempWord.Substring(0, tempWord.Length - 1)

        let phonems = Regex.Split(tempWord, "[^aeiouy]+")

        let mutable syl = 0;

        for i = 0 to SubSyl.Length - 1 do
            let syllabe = SubSyl.[i];
            if Regex.IsMatch( tempWord, syllabe) then 
                syl <- syl - 1

        for i = 0 to AddSyl.Length - 1 do
            let syllabe = AddSyl.[i];
            if Regex.IsMatch( tempWord, syllabe) then 
                syl <- syl + 1

        if tempWord.Length = 1 then
            syl <- syl + 1

        for i = 0 to phonems.Length - 1 do
            if phonems.[i].Length > 0 then
                syl <- syl + 1

        if syl = 0 then
            syl <- 1

        // return
        syl

//https://github.com/DaveChild/Text-Statistics/blob/master/src/DaveChild/TextStatistics/Syllables.php

let problemWordMap =
    dict[
        ("abalone", 4);
        ("abare", 3);
        ("abed" , 2);
        ("abruzzese", 4);
        ("abbruzzese" , 4);
        ("aborigine", 5);
        ("aborigines", 5); //andrew plural (ap)
        ("acreage", 3);
        ("acreage", 3); //ap
        ("adame", 3);
        ("adieu", 2);
        ("adobe", 3);
        ("anemone", 4);
        ("anemones", 4); //ap
        ("apache" , 3);
        ("apaches" , 3); //ap
        ("aphrodite", 4);
        ("apostrophe" , 4);
        ("apostrophes" , 4); //ap
        ("ariadne", 4);
        ("cafe" , 2);
        ("cafes" , 2); //ap
        ("calliope" , 4);
        ("catastrophe", 4);
        ("catastrophes", 4); //ap
        ("chile", 2);
        ("chiles", 2); //ap
        ("chloe", 2);
        ("circe", 2);
        ("coyote" , 3);
        ("coyotes" , 3); //ap
        ("epitome", 4);
        ("forever", 3);
        ("gethsemane" , 4);
        ("guacamole", 4);
        ("guacamoles", 4); //ap
        ("hyperbole", 4);
        ("hyperboles", 4); //ap
        ("jesse", 2);
        ("jukebox", 2);
        ("jukeboxes", 2); //ap
        ("karate" , 3);
        ("karates" , 3); //ap
        ("machete", 3);
        ("maybe", 2);
        ("people" , 2);
        ("recipe" , 3);
        ("sesame" , 3);
        ("shoreline", 2);
        ("simile" , 3);
        ("machetes", 3); //ap
        ("maybes", 2);//ap
        ("peoples" , 2);//ap
        ("recipes" , 3);//ap
        ("sesames" , 3);//ap
        ("shorelines", 2);//ap
        ("similes" , 3);//ap
        ("syncope", 3);
        ("tamale" , 3);
        ("tamales" , 3); //ap
        ("yosemite" , 4);
        ("daphne" , 2);
        ("eurydice" , 4);
        ("euterpe", 3);
        ("hermione" , 4);
        ("penelope" , 4);
        ("persephone" , 4);
        ("phoebe" , 2);
        ("zoe", 2);
    ]

// These syllables would be counted as two but should be one
let oneSyllableCorrection =
    [|
        "cia(l|$)"; // glacial, acacia
        "tia";
        "cius";
        "cious";
        "[^aeiou]giu";
        "[aeiouy][^aeiouy]ion";
        "iou";
        "sia$";
        "eous$";
        "[oa]gue$";
        ".[^aeiuoycgltdb]{2,}ed$";
        ".ely$";
        //"[cg]h?ed?$";
        //"rved?$";
        //"[aeiouy][dt]es?$";
        //"^[dr]e[aeiou][^aeiou]+$"; // Sorts out deal, deign etc
        //"[aeiouy]rse$"; // Purse, hearse
        "^jua";
        //"nne[ds]?$"; // canadienne
        "uai"; // acquainted
        "eau"; // champeau
        //"pagne[ds]?$"; // champagne
        //"[aeiouy][^aeiuoytdbcgrnzs]h?e[rsd]?$";
        // The following detects words ending with a soft e ending. Don";t
        // mess with it unless you absolutely have to! The following
        // is a list of words you can use to test a new version of
        // this rule (add ";r";, ";s"; and ";d"; where possible to test
        // fully):
        //   - absolve
        //   - acquiesce
        //   - audience
        //   - ache
        //   - acquire
        //   - brunelle
        //   - byrne
        //   - canadienne
        //   - coughed
        //   - curved
        //   - champagne
        //   - designate
        //   - force
        //   - lace
        //   - late
        //   - lathe
        //   - make
        //   - relayed
        //   - scrounge
        //   - side
        //   - sideline
        //   - some
        //   - wide
        //   - taste
        "[aeiouy](b|c|ch|d|dg|f|g|gh|gn|k|l|ll|lv|m|mm|n|nc|ng|nn|p|r|rc|rn|rs|rv|s|sc|sk|sl|squ|ss|st|t|th|v|y|z)e$";
        // For soft e endings with a "d". Test words:
        //   - crunched
        //   - forced
        //   - hated
        //   - sided
        //   - sidelined
        //   - unexploded
        //   - unexplored
        //   - scrounged
        //   - squelched
        //   - forced
        "[aeiouy](b|c|ch|dg|f|g|gh|gn|k|l|lch|ll|lv|m|mm|n|nc|ng|nch|nn|p|r|rc|rn|rs|rv|s|sc|sk|sl|squ|ss|th|v|y|z)ed$";
        // For soft e endings with a "s". Test words:
        //   - absences
        //   - accomplices
        //   - acknowledges
        //   - advantages
        //   - byrnes
        //   - crunches
        //   - forces
        //   - scrounges
        //   - squelches
        "[aeiouy](b|ch|d|f|gh|gn|k|l|lch|ll|lv|m|mm|n|nch|nn|p|r|rn|rs|rv|s|sc|sk|sl|squ|ss|st|t|th|v|y)es$";
        "^busi$";
    |] |> String.concat("|") |> Regex


// These syllables would be counted as one but should be two
let twoSyllableCorrection =
    [|
        "([^s]|^)ia";
        "riet";
        "dien"; // audience
        "iu";
        "io";
        "eo($|[b-df-hj-np-tv-z])";
        "ii";
        "[ou]a$";
        "[aeiouym]bl$";
        "[aeiou]{3}";
        "[aeiou]y[aeiou]";
        "^mc";
        "ism$";
        "asm$";
        "thm$";
        "([^aeiouy])\1l$";
        "[^l]lien";
        "^coa[dglx].";
        "[^gq]ua[^auieo]";
        "dnt$";
        "uity$";
        "[^aeiouy]ie(r|st|t)$";
        "eings?$";
        "[aeiouy]sh?e[rsd]$";
        "iell";
        "dea$";
        "real"; // real, cereal
        "[^aeiou]y[ae]"; // bryan, byerley
        "gean$"; // aegean
        "uen"; // influence, affluence

    |] |> String.concat("|") |> Regex

// Single syllable prefixes and suffixes
let oneSyllableAffix =
    [|
        "^un";
        "^fore";
        "^ware";
        "^none?";
        "^out";
        "^post";
        "^sub";
        "^pre";
        "^pro";
        "^dis";
        "^side";
        "ly$";
        "less$";
        "some$";
        "ful$";
        "ers?$";
        "ness$";
        "cians?$";
        "ments?$";
        "ettes?$";
        "villes?$";
        "ships?$";
        "sides?$";
        "ports?$";
        "shires?$";
        "tion(ed)?$";

    |] |> String.concat("|") |> Regex

// Double syllable prefixes and suffixes
let twoSyllableAffix =
    [|
        "^above";
        "^ant[ie]";
        "^counter";
        "^hyper";
        "^afore";
        "^agri";
        "^in[ft]ra";
        "^inter";
        "^over";
        "^semi";
        "^ultra";
        "^under";
        "^extra";
        "^dia";
        "^micro";
        "^mega";
        "^kilo";
        "^pico";
        "^nano";
        "^macro";
        "berry$";
        "woman$";
        "women$";

    |] |> String.concat("|") |> Regex

// Triple syllable prefixes and suffixes
let threeSyllableAffix =
    [|
        "ology$";
        "ologist$";
        "onomy$";
        "onomist$";
    |] |> String.concat("|") |> Regex

/// <summary>
/// For each match in pattern, replace match with empty string in input word,
/// returning bare word and # matches
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pattern"></param>
/// <param name="word"></param>
let RegexReplace (regex:Regex) word =
    //let affixReplace = new Regex( pattern )
    let matches = regex.Matches(word)
    let mutable bareWord = word
    for aMatch in matches do
        bareWord <- bareWord.Replace(aMatch.Value,"")
    //
    bareWord, matches.Count //need to exclude a group?

let CountMatches (regex:Regex) word =
    //let regex = new Regex( pattern )
    let matches = regex.Matches(word)
    //
    matches.Count

/// <summary>
/// Counts syllables in word. Assumes word has already been "cleaned"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="word"></param>
let SyllableCount( word : string) =
    if problemWordMap.ContainsKey( word ) then
        problemWordMap.[word]
    else
        //remove and count affixes
        let wordMinus1Affix, oneAffixCount = RegexReplace oneSyllableAffix word
        let wordMinus2Affix, twoAffixCount = RegexReplace twoSyllableAffix wordMinus1Affix
        let wordMinus3Affix, threeAffixCount = RegexReplace threeSyllableAffix wordMinus2Affix

        //count word parts
        let vowelSplit = Regex.Split(wordMinus3Affix, "[^aeiouy]")
        let mutable wordPartCount = 0
        for wordPart in vowelSplit do
            if wordPart.Length > 0 then
                wordPartCount <- wordPartCount + 1

        //base syllable count
        let mutable baseSyllableCount = oneAffixCount + twoAffixCount + threeAffixCount + wordPartCount

        //handle degenerate cases
        let oneSyllableCorrectionCount = CountMatches oneSyllableCorrection word //count two as one: subtract
        let twoSyllableCorrectionCount = CountMatches twoSyllableCorrection word //count one as two: add

        baseSyllableCount <- baseSyllableCount - oneSyllableCorrectionCount + twoSyllableCorrectionCount

        //we always have 1 syllable in a word
        if baseSyllableCount > 0 then
            baseSyllableCount
        else
            1
```

To handle sentence counting, I used the nuget package for the Stanford parser and created this wrapper:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using edu.stanford.nlp.process;
using edu.stanford.nlp.util;

namespace StanfordWrapper
{
    public class SentenceTokenizer
    {
        public static readonly TokenizerFactory TokenizerFactory = PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(),
                "normalizeParentheses=false,normalizeOtherBrackets=false,invertible=true");

        public static List<string> Go( string input )
        {
            java.io.Reader reader = new java.io.StringReader(input);
            DocumentPreprocessor dp = new DocumentPreprocessor(reader);
            dp.setTokenizerFactory(TokenizerFactory);

            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            foreach (java.util.List sentence in dp)
            {
                output.Add(StringUtils.joinWithOriginalWhiteSpace(sentence));
            }

            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

A wrapper is helpful b/c the parser is in java. The nuget uses IKVMC to make it callable by .NET.

Finally for word counting I use some code to clean/tokenize:

```
module TextNormalizer

open System;
open System.Collections.Generic;
open System.Linq;
open System.Text.RegularExpressions;

let spaceRegex = new Regex(@"\s+");
let normalizeTextRegexStrict = new Regex( String.Join("|", [| @"[^\w\s]"; @"[0-9]+"; "_" |]), RegexOptions.Compiled);
let normalizeTextRegexApostrophe = new Regex( String.Join("|", [| @"[^'\w\s]"; @"[0-9]+"; "_" |]), RegexOptions.Compiled);

/// <summary>
/// Replaces all punctuation with whitspace, apostrophe optional. Will return string matching original text with punctuation
/// removed, text lowercased, and words evenly delimited with whitespace
/// </summary>
/// <param name="normedLine"></param>
/// <param name="removeApostrophe"></param>
let Normalize( normedLine ) ( removeApostrophe ) =
    let normedLine =
        if removeApostrophe then
            normalizeTextRegexStrict.Replace(normedLine, " "); // replace all punctuation with whitespace
        else
            normalizeTextRegexApostrophe.Replace(normedLine, " "); // replace all except apostrophe with whitespace

    //return
    spaceRegex.Replace( normedLine, " " )  // reduce continguous whitespace to a single space
        .Trim()                                         // get rid of any whitespace on ends
        .ToLower();                                     // lowercase whole thing
```

With all those things in place it is trivial to compute FK:

```
let FleshKincaidGradeLevel( text ) =
    let sentences = StanfordWrapper.SentenceTokenizer.Go( text ) |> Seq.toArray

    let words =  sentences |> Array.map( fun x ->  TextNormalizer.Normalize x false ) |> Array.collect( fun x -> x.Split( ' ' ))

    let syllableCount = words |> Array.map SyllableCount2 |> Array.sum

    //FKGL formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_tests
    ( 0.39 * ( float words.Length) / (float sentences.Length ) ) + ( 11.8 * (float syllableCount ) / ( float words.Length) ) - 15.59
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised there aren't libraries for this, but do you really need it?

If you can get to your raw text the calculation is rather trivial.

Looking at the source code of [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fleschkincaid/) (PHP) counting syllables is done just like counting sentences, using regexps, but instead of splitting on .!? split on all the vowels aeiouy.

Comment: That's a very rough assumption, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1076924/1226839 for more info about why (or look at the multi-vowel words in this sentence :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is an open-source solution in Java - it's not .Net, but it is relatively clear code that you could probably translate: https://github.com/ipeirotis/ReadabilityMetrics (in Java) which is in turn based on http://search.cpan.org/author/GREGFAST/Lingua-EN-Syllable-0.251/ (in Perl).