# Flesch-Kincaid Readability in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, flesch-kincaid

I'm working on an asp.net content management system and we need to have [Flesch-Kincaid grade level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_test) stats available to the users.  I've done quite a bit of searching and I haven't found any viable ways to implement this.  The closest I've come is [the MS Word ReadabilityStatistics Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151097/flesch-kincaid-readability-test).  I can get this to work great in a console app but support for the dll in asp.net isn't supported and I get an access denied error whenever I try to leverage it from my asp.net application.  I spent 8 hours the other day trying to get that to work from asp.net with no luck.

Does anyone know of another dll or method to get a FK value?  We do tell our content users that the FK value is from MS word, so that'd be best, but really anything which is close would be appreciated at this point.  Even an js version would be adequate.

Comment: I'm guessing you've read the other q on the same subject; I've linked it so that no one is tempted to close this as a duplicate. You might find it useful to ask another, separate, question detailing the difficulties you had using Word from your ASP.NET application.

Comment: Absolutely,  I get the following error:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I've tried everything in [this forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/65a355ce-49c1-47f1-8c12-d9cf5f23c53e) with no luck.

I'm using .Net 4.0 on Win7, I've tried both 32 and 64 bit versions of MS Word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy translating PHP, [the work has been done for you](https://github.com/DaveChild/Text-Statistics).

Comment: +1 for the link, syllable count would be tricky to implement properly IMHO.

Comment: Hmmm... I got a downvote recently for suggesting in an answer that someone take a PHP solution and translate it to C#/ASP.NET. I won't do that to you though.

Comment: Thanks AakashM, Looks like this may be my only option.

Comment: Successfully translated from PHP.  Thanks again.

Comment: @miniMan, is the translated code available for c# publicly?

Comment: @AmirSasson, sorry - It was not made public and I no longer have access to that codebase.